# How to write Generic Rule based makefile

Tags: makefile

I have following folder structure

```
    --Makefile
    --source/
        --boot.s
        --kernel.c
        --linker.ld
    --build/
```

and I compile my sources using following Makefile

```
###############################################################################
#
#   A makefile script for generation of raspberry pi kernel images.
#
###############################################################################

# The toolchain to use. arm-none-eabi works, but there does exist 
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-gcc

# The intermediate directory for compiled object files.
BUILD = build/

# The directory in which source files are stored.
SOURCE = source/

CFLAGS =    -march=armv8-a+crc \
            -mcpu=cortex-a53 \
            -mtune=cortex-a53 \
            -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 \
            -mfloat-abi=hard \
            -ftree-vectorize \
            -funsafe-math-optimizations \
            -O2 -pipe -ffreestanding

LDFLAGS = -T $(SOURCE)linker.ld -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib


# The name of the output file to generate.
TARGET = kernel.img

.PHONY: all clean run

# Rule to make everything.
all: $(TARGET)

# Rule to remake everything. Does not include clean.
rebuild: clean all 

#Rule to invoke qemu
run:
    qemu-system-arm -m 256 -M raspi2 -serial stdio -kernel $(BUILD)kernel.elf

$(TARGET): kernel.elf
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy $(BUILD)kernel.elf -O binary $(BUILD)kernel.img

kernel.elf: boot.o kernel.o
    $(LD)   $(LDFLAGS) -o $(BUILD)kernel.elf $(BUILD)boot.o $(BUILD)kernel.o

boot.o: $(SOURCE)boot.s
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)boot.s -o $(BUILD)boot.o

kernel.o: $(SOURCE)boot.s
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)kernel.c -o $(BUILD)kernel.o

# Rule to clean files.
clean : 
    -rm -f $(BUILD)*
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f *.elf
    -rm -f *.img
```

How to write pattern based rules ? I tried many stack overflow answers but couldn't make it work.

First I listed my source using wild cards but couldn't write proper target as sources list had [source/boot.s source/kernel.c] and it would create object files in source folder it self.

I was facing difficulty while keeping sources and build directory different. Any help is appreciated.

**----------Complete solution as per @MadScientist -----------**

```
###############################################################################
#
#   A makefile script for generation of raspberry pi kernel images.
#
###############################################################################

# The toolchain to use. arm-none-eabi works, but there does exist 
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc
LD = arm-none-eabi-gcc

# The intermediate directory for compiled object files.
BUILD = build/

# The directory in which source files are stored.
SOURCE = source/

CFLAGS =    -march=armv8-a+crc \
            -mcpu=cortex-a53 \
            -mtune=cortex-a53 \
            -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8 \
            -mfloat-abi=hard \
            -ftree-vectorize \
            -funsafe-math-optimizations \
            -O2 -pipe -ffreestanding

LDFLAGS = -T $(SOURCE)linker.ld -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib

SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.s) $(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCE)%,$(BUILD)%.o,$(basename $(SOURCES)))

# The name of the output file to generate.
TARGET = kernel.img

.PHONY: all clean run

# Rule to make everything.
all: $(BUILD)$(TARGET)

# Rule to remake everything. Does not include clean.
rebuild: clean all 

#Rule to invoke qemu
run:
    qemu-system-arm -m 256 -M raspi2 -serial stdio -kernel $(BUILD)kernel.elf

$(BUILD)%.o : $(SOURCE)%.s
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD)%.o : $(SOURCE)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD)$(TARGET): $(BUILD)kernel.elf
    arm-none-eabi-objcopy $< -O binary $@

$(BUILD)kernel.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

# Rule to clean files.
clean : 
    -rm -f $(BUILD)*
    -rm -f *.o
    -rm -f *.elf
    -rm -f *.img
```

Comment: You say "I tried many [things] but couldn't make it work".  When asking a question, show what you tried, show the command you ran, show the result you got (cut and paste, not paraphrase), and explain why that output wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I will edit my question and add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
boot.o: $(SOURCE)boot.s
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SOURCE)boot.s -o $(BUILD)boot.o
```

You are telling make that your recipe will build a file named `boot.o`, but it doesn't: it creates a file named `$(BUILD)boot.o`, which is completely different.  Same with your rules to build `kernel.img` and `kernel.elf`.

If you want to write a pattern rule the `%` can match only identical parts.  Since `SOURCE` and `BUILD` are not identical, they won't match the `%` part.  So you have to write this:

```
$(BUILD)%.o : $(SOURCE)%.s
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Since you're building `$(BUILD)xxx.o` you have to use that as a prerequisite as well, so you have to write:

```
$(BUILD)$(TARGET): $(BUILD)kernel.elf
        arm-none-eabi-objcopy $< -O binary $@

$(BUILD)kernel.elf: $(BUILD)boot.o $(BUILD)kernel.o
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

*ETA*

If you want to get the source files via wildcard you can, but you have to substitute the directory as well not just the suffix, like this:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.s)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCE)%.s,$(BUILD)%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

If you have both assembly and C source files (you didn't show any C source files in your example makefile) you can use this:

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.s) $(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.c)
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCE)%,$(BUILD)%.o,$(basename $(SOURCES)))
```

Comment: I included that in my Makefile.  But had to add something to it.


    `SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.s) $(wildcard $(SOURCE)*.c)
    OBJECTS = $(filter %.o, \
           $(patsubst $(SOURCE)%.s, $(BUILD)%.o,$(SOURCES)) \
            $(patsubst $(SOURCE)%.c, $(BUILD)%.o,$(SOURCES)))

    $(BUILD)kernel.elf: $(OBJECTS)
        $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^`

Comment: As you can see you cannot add formatted content into comments in SO.  You'll have to edit your question instead to make it readably formatted.  I updated my answer.